# How to get size without unnecessary area in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

You can get the usage size per database with the following SQL. However, I think this also includes unnecessary areas.

```
select pg_database_size ('DBNAME');
```

Is there a way to get the size as close as possible to the size after VACUUM without doing VACUUM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are talking about `VACUUM (FULL)` rather than `VACUUM`, which is something entirely different (normal `VACUUM` usually doesn't reclaim any storage space).

There are a couple of queries out there that try to estimate the amount of bloat in PostgreSQL tables (see http://wiki.postgresql.org), but none of these is quite accurate.

To find the exact amount of bloat in a PostgreSQL table, use the [`pgstattuple`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgstattuple.html) function in the extension of the same name, but be warned that it performs a sequential scan of the whole table (the `pgstattuple
_approx` function provides a good approximation without scanning the whole table).

Comment: Thank you very much.
Yes, that's what I meant by VACUUM FULL.

> pgstattuple function
Yes. It was very helpful.

By the way, this is not a standard feature, is it?
Isn't there a way to achieve this with only standard features, even if it's an approximation?

Comment: That *is* a standard feature. The "contrib" modules are part of the source of core PostgreSQL.